# Xamarin.IOS: Can't load image from Images.xcassets

Tags: ios, iphone, image, xamarin, uiimageview

Im working on **Xamarin Studio**, and I have a **Storyboard** which contains a **UIImageView**, its properties are set like this :

[image]

You can notice that chosen image is called `personalPhoto` which exists in the **Images.xcassets** like this

[image]

But when I run the app in the simulator, the image isn't loaded .. and the **UIImageView** looks empty

[image]

Even if try to add the **UIImageView** programatically using this code.. it gives me the same result

```
UIImageView personImage = new UIImageView {
    Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, 200, 200),
    Image = UIImage.FromBundle("personalPhoto"),
    ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
};
this.View.AddSubview (personImage);
```

So do you have any idea what is the problem .. please give me some help ..

And thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart your iPhone or Simulator and try again.

You can also clean (Product -> clean) and try again

Comment: Thanks a lot .. it worked using (Build -> Clean all)